# How to copy a file while locking the destination in Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi

My Windows service needs to be able to copy a file and keep the destination locked after the copy is done so we can do some work with the copy while preventing other processes (at least ones which aren't also running as SYSTEM) having a chance to read the new file during a window after my service copies it but before it can lock it again.

The only way I can think of to make sure this happens is to manually create the destination file and copy the data myself, and give up on using CopyFile or its variants entirely. Does anyone have a nicer solution than that?

Comment: Doesn't seem anything else is available. However, what's the actual benefit of CopyFile? It can be done in C++ with two lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, you're right; I was basically just trying to avoid those two lines.
Also I do need to open the destination as a Win32 handle so that I can use some slightly more exotic API calls on it. So since I assume those two lines would involve C++ iostreams, that's probably a low estimate.

Comment: Yes, they would involve iostreams. Well, sorry, no better answer.

Comment: Are you sure `CopyFile` opens the target file with sharing allowed?

Comment: I'm realizing now I could have made this a bit clearer. I'm going to edit the question. My problem is that CopyFile doesn't leave the destination open/locked after the copy is done. That creates a window where another process can open the file.

Comment: You'll probably need to write your own copy function if you want to do that.

Comment: @SergeyA CopyFile of Windows is heavily optimized and you'll not get that by the two lines of code _if you need that performance_.

Comment: @goldfire, why don't you copy the file to a randomly generated name in the destination folder, lock it, modify it and then rename to the original one with overwrite ?

Comment: @goldfire in any case, if you are trying to achieve some form of security by going this route, you'll quickly see that it is not enough.

Comment: You cannot prevent *absolutely* everything from reading the file while writing it. Consider shadow copies, various filesystem filters and other such things. Be reasonable, be simpler.